Movie where a patient with multiple personalities is an evil spirit?
I'm looking for the name of this movie. I can't remember who's in it, and I only remember bits of the plot.
I remember the main character (a woman I think) is a psychiatrist who doesn't believe in multiple personality disorder, but is invited by a former colleague to examine a criminally insane patient whom he claims suffers from it.
She interviews the patient with skepticism at first, but slowly comes around to the idea that her colleague might actually be right. She was finally convinced when she administered a "hidden number" test to a particular persona that claimed to be colorblind (a reverse color-dot test that only colorblind people can see). All of the other personas had color-normal vision.
The big reveal in the movie is that the patient is actually just a normal guy that has been possessed by some kind of demon or ghost that kills people.
I remember at one point the main character went to a ranch in the woods run by a cult leader (a witch I think) who had specific knowledge of this demon and how to kill it. It winds up taking over her daughter's body.
Does anybody know what movie I'm talking about? I'd really like to watch it again.

Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Anything at all? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions.

This could be 6 Souls realeased in 2010 (origninally named Shelter)
Links

IMDB page
Wikipedia page

Story line

After the death of her husband, Dr. Cara Harding's faith in God has been shaken, but not her belief in science. In an attempt to get her more open to accepting unexplainable psychiatric theories, her father introduces her to Adam, a patient with multiple personalities who also takes on some of the physical characteristics of his other personalities. But Cara quickly discovers that his other personalities were murder victims and the more she finds out about Adam and his past, the closer she and her loved ones are to becoming murder victims themselves

Specific scenes and characters
She does the "color blind" test on her patient, the number 7 could only be seen by color blind people and the patient see it :

There is a "cult leader witch" living int the woods


Yup that's the one! Interesting... The reviews on this movie are horrible but I don't remember it being that bad.
